# get foreign key from model

Tags: python, django

I want to get `pk` from model.

**model.py**

```
class Produit(models.Model):
    ref=models.CharField(max_length=100, default='',primary_key=True)
    marq=models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    nomp=models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    qte = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    codecateg=models.ForeignKey(categorie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class categorie(models.Model):
    codecateg=models.CharField(max_length=100, default='' , primary_key=True)
    nomcat=models.CharField(max_length=30, default='' )
```

**views.py**

```
def edit_prod(request , id = None):
    ins = get_object_or_404(Produit,ref=id)
    datedit = {'ins': ins}
    return render(request, 'produit/modal_prode.html',datedit )
```

When I want to get `ins.codecateg` I get `categorie` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 'produit/modal_prode.html' you are sending `Produit` object, so `ins` is the object, and when you do `ins.codecateg` it will get the `categorie` object associated with it, but if you wnat to get the `categorie` pk you would have to

```
<h4>{{ ins.codecateg.pk }}</h4>
```

in html.

Answer (score 1):

if what you want is `pk`

```
ins.codecateg.pk
```